# How do I get project information while in an mvc controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I get the site's version numbers [Major].[Minor].[Revision].[Build] at runtime in the HomeController.cs? I plan to display that information in the footer of my website...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the version of the current assembly that is hosting your controller:

```
var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

But if you are going to display this on the footer of your website, you'd rather write a custom HTML helper instead of polluting all your controllers with this:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString SiteVersion(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        var version = typeof(HtmlExtensions).Assembly.GetName().Version;
        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("[{0}].[{1}].[{2}].[{3}]", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Revision, version.Build));
    }
}
```

and then in your footer:

```
@Html.SiteVersion()
```